# how to create java zip archives with a max file size limit

Tags: java, android

I need to write an algorithm in java (for an android app) to read a folder containing more folders and each of those containing images and audio files so the structure is this: `mainDir/subfolders/myFile1.jpg`

- <sup>It must be in java, something like perl script is not an option. It would preferably be for the compressed archive in order to squeeze as many files as possible before mailing the zip. Just a normal zip (no jar).</sup>

My problem is that I need to limit the size of the archive to 16mb and at runtime, create as many archives as needed to contain all my files from my main `mainDir` folder. I tried several examples from the net, I read the java documentation, but I can't manage to understand and put it all together the way I need it.

Has someone done this before or has a link or an example for me? I resolved the reading of the files with a recursive method but I can't figure the logic for the zip creation.

**EDIT:** [FileNotFoundException (no such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084823/filenotfoundexception-no-such-file-or-directory) this was my initial post at Stack Overflow. I've got an answer to it, but I can't set the size of the ZipEntry and the logic doesn't work and also when extracting the my files from the zip I get the `compression method not supported` error.

Comment: Does this have to be in Java?  Would a (for example) perl script to create the archives be acceptable?  Is the limit on the size of the compressed or uncompressed archive?  Is this a .jar (with manifests and the like) or just a simple .zip?

Comment: It must be in java yes. It would preferably be for the compressed archive in order to squeeze as many files as possible before mailing the zip. Just a normal zip (no jar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size limit (16 mb or whatever) does not enforce you to have archive size as close to it as possible.

Assuming that you are allowed to create archives of smaller size, here is the "first iteration" solution - dead simple, but meets your requirements: just zip every file into separate archive.

1. `myFile1` -> `archive1.zip`
2. `myFile2` -> `archive2.zip`
3. etc

Now, if you want it a bit less dumb, use the sum of current archive size ([Deflater.getBytesWritten()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#getBytesWritten%28%29)) and **next uncompressed file** size to decide if it's time to switch to creating new archive.

1. `myFile1` -> `archive1.zip`
2. size of `archive1.zip` plus `myFile2` within limit -> add `myFile2` to `archive1`
3. size of `archive1.zip` plus `myFile3` exceeds limit -> add `myFile3` to new zip, `archive2`
   <sub>Yeah there is a chance that adding *compressed* myFile3 to archive1 will remain within limit, but why bother?</sub>
4. etc

Comment: Good point! I will try to implement your logic tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: @maple_shaft I too thought it was a poor question, until I read [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243992/how-to-split-a-huge-zip-file-into-multiple-volumes) mentioned at prior SO post from the OP and discovered that straightforward approach is really tough _"Took about a day to write and 2 days to debug. ...zip specification - section K has the info you are looking for specifically, but you'll need to read A, B, C and F as well..."_ That made me think, what the hell section K and A, B, C and WTF as well... question is not that easy as it looks

Comment: @MarciCăşvan `some people abuse their power` If that's a comment on maple_shaft closing the question, I fully support his decision. I only re-opened it after gnat edited it into shape, and that's how it's supposed to work. Moderators are not here to fix every question, that's what the community is for, the process was followed perfectly for your question and I strongly believe that there was no abuse of power here.

Comment: thanks for the response I successfully managed ti implement the logic

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Java 7? If so then it has native support for [Zip archives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) in the new NIO.2 APIs

> The zip file system provider introduced in the Java SE 7 release is an implementation of a custom file system provider. The zip file system provider treats a zip or JAR file as a file system and provides the ability to manipulate the contents of the file. The zip file system provider creates multiple file systems — one file system for each zip or JAR file.
>
> The `demo/nio/zipfs/src.zip` file in your Java SE 7 installation contains the source code for the zip file system provider. It also contains the `Demo.java` class that shows how to use the zip file system provider...
>
> You can use the factory methods of the [`java.nio.file.FileSystems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) class to create a new zip file system or to obtain a reference to an existing zip file system...

Comment: I need to check out the version of java. Thanks, I will look up the  new NIO.2 API's tomorrow and get back with an answer.